# Launch popup message from service

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I need to launch a popup message from a service when a message is received from the server.  I can use `toast` and the message is displayed when the app is in the foreground or the background, exactly what I need EXCEPT I need to capture the response to the message so `toast` or a `notification` will not work for me.  I have the following code:

```
public async void showMessage(string message)
{

    Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.SetTitle("Message");
    alert.SetMessage(message);
    alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) => {
        // I need to construct a number of buttons to capture user response, not just "Ok"
    });
    Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
    dialog.Window.SetType(Android.Views.WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert);
    dialog.Show();

    //ToastLength duration = ToastLength.Short;

    //var toast = Toast.MakeText(context, message, duration);
    //toast.Show();
 }
```

This method is called from this line in the service:

```
mHandler.Post(() => { showMessage(message); });
```

I have set all the appropriate permissions in the manifest.  When I run the code I get the error:

```
Exception:

Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException
```

This is my service code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;
using Java.Util.Concurrent;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports;


namespace MyAndroid
{
    [Service]
    public class SignalRSrv : Service
    {
        private bool InstanceFieldsInitialized = false;
        private string username = "";
        private string firstname = "";
        private string lastname = "";
        private string company= "";
        private string department = "";
        private string section = "";

        private void InitializeInstanceFields()
        {
            mBinder = new LocalBinder(this);
        }

        private Handler mHandler; // to display any received messages
        private IBinder mBinder; // Binder given to clients
        private SignalRSingleton mInstance;

        public SignalRSrv()
        {
            if (!InstanceFieldsInitialized)
            {
                InitializeInstanceFields();
                InstanceFieldsInitialized = true;
            }

        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            mInstance = SignalRSingleton.getInstance();
            mHandler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
        }


        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {

            //binder = new LocalBinder(this);
            User MyUser = new User("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
            Bundle bundlee = intent.GetBundleExtra("TheBundle");
            MyUser = bundlee.GetParcelable("MyUser") as User;

            username = MyUser.Username;
            firstname = MyUser.Firstname;
            lastname = MyUser.Lastname;
            company = intent.GetStringExtra("theSelectedCompany");
            department = intent.GetStringExtra("theSelectedDepartment");
            section = intent.GetStringExtra("theSelectedSection");

            startSignalR();
            return mBinder;
        }

        private void startSignalR()
        {
            mInstance.setmHubConnection(username, firstname,lastname,company,department,section);
            mInstance.setHubProxy();

            try
            {
                // Connect the client to the hup
                mInstance.mHubConnection.Start();

                mInstance.mHubProxy.On("broadcastMessage", (string platform, string message) =>
                {
                    mHandler.Post(() => { showMessage(message); });
                });

            }
            catch (System.Exception e) when (e is InterruptedException || e is ExecutionException)
            {
                //opps

                var x = 1;
                return;
            }
        }

        public async void showMessage(string message)
        {


            try
            {
                Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.SetTitle("Message");
                alert.SetMessage(message);
                alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) => {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Ok button Tapped!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                });
                Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
                dialog.Window.SetType(Android.Views.WindowManagerTypes.Toast);
                dialog.Show();

            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                var s = e.Message;
            }


            //AlertDialog alert = builder.Create();

            //alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            //alert.show();

        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {

            User MyUser = new User("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
            Bundle bundlee = intent.GetBundleExtra("TheBundle");
            MyUser = bundlee.GetParcelable("MyUser") as User;

            username = MyUser.Username;
            firstname = MyUser.Firstname;
            lastname = MyUser.Lastname;
            company = intent.GetStringExtra("theSelectedCompany");
            department = intent.GetStringExtra("theSelectedDepartment");
            section = intent.GetStringExtra("theSelectedsection");

            startSignalR();
            RegisterForegroundService();

            // This tells Android not to restart the service if it is killed to reclaim resources.
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        void RegisterForegroundService()
        {
            var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .SetContentTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name))
                .SetContentText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.notification_text))
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.alert_box)
                .SetOngoing(true)
                .Build();


            // Enlist this instance of the service as a foreground service
            StartForeground(Constants.SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }

    }
    public class LocalBinder : Binder
    {
        private readonly SignalRSrv outerInstance;

        public LocalBinder(SignalRSrv outerInstance)
        {
            this.outerInstance = outerInstance;
        }

        public virtual SignalRSrv Service
        {
            get
            {
                // Return this instance of SignalRService so clients can call public methods
                return outerInstance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="OML_Android.OML_Android" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
<service android:name=".SignalRSrv" android:label="Messenger" android:enabled="true"></service>
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></application>
```

I've searched all over for a solution and all that I have found suggest that `Types.SystemAlert` or `Types.ApplicationOverlay` with the appropriate permission in the manifest solves the issue, but that's apparently not the case anymore.  Given that all the "solutions" I have found are between 4 and 8 years old, they are obviously obsolete, not to mention they are written in java, not c# which just makes it all that more difficult to understand for me.  Seems like no one writes these things in c#.  In any event, I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: If you could provide more details with regards to this it would really help me out finding a solution for you. Like for example, Stacktrace and full Message(Exception)!!

Comment: The full error is: `Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> occurred
`

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling it from a background thread and that you are using the service's context to display the `AlertDialog`?

Comment: This is the message I get when I trap the error: `"Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?"`

Comment: Added my service code where the call is made.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine, so you should also have `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission I assume!

Comment: That is set ... in visual studio 2017, it's `Android.Views.WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert`.  And I set the permission as well.

Comment: I am talking about the permission in Manifest sir!!! Something like this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />`

Comment: Yup, that is set as well.

Comment: Also, do you have permission to draw over other apps? For Marshmallow and above?

Comment: Added my manifest .....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194900/discussion-between-g-hakim-and-prescott-chartier).

Comment: Sorry it was late night here and I kinda slept, also you can call startActivityForResult from an activity

Comment: Yes, you can call startActivityForResult from an activity, but the popup is started from the service.

Comment: Yeah right so were you able to make this much work?

Comment: No, doesn't work from the service.

Answer (score 0):

Draw over other apps permission can be invoked something like this in xamarin:

```
 private const int RequestCode = 1000;

    private void CheckForOverlayPermission()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.M) return;
        if (!Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this)) return;

        var intent = new Intent(Settings.ActionManageOverlayPermission);
        intent.SetPackage(PackageName);
        StartActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == RequestCode)
        {
            if (Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this))
            {
                // we have permission
            }
        }

        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the recent updates to the android OS, it is now impossible to do this so I had to push a notification rather than show a popup.  I've got the notification working in my service, next I will figure out how to have it bring the app to the foreground when the user taps the notification.  My (now working) service and notification code is at this link:
[Send notification from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56610433/send-notification-from-service?noredirect=1#comment99825770_56610433)